# How to change the animation of transition from one AbilitySlice to another AbilitySlice in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In Android, we can add the following statement to the `onBackPressed()` function to modify the animation of going back to the MainActivity from some other activity.

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

How can we do so in HarmonyOS? What different animations are available in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the team, Currently HarmonyOS does not support animation customization during the transition of `AbilitySlice`. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.